# How to store an array in session in Perl

Tags: perl, mojolicious, strawberry-perl

I am using Mojolicious Perl framework in my application. I want to store an array in session, but is not successful.

```
my @returnResult;
$returnResult['fn'] = $decoded->{'fn'};
$returnResult['ln'] = $decoded->{'ln'};
$self->session(returnResult => @returnResult);
```

Please help.

Comment: do you `use strict; use warnings;` ?  don't you get the message `argument 'fn' isn't numeric in array element` ?

Comment: Yes. I am using strict and warnings. I am getting message argument 'fn' isn't numeric in array element

Comment: so, why don't you use numeric arguments instead of "fn" and "ln"?

Comment: As it is more readable. How can I use associative arrays in Perl?

Comment: you can have a look here :) http://www.google.com

Comment: "associative arrays" are called hashes in Perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [*hashes* in Modern Perl](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2016/03-perl-language.html#SGFzaGVz) and [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html).

```
my %return_result;
$returnResult{fn} = $decoded->{fn};
$returnResult{ln} = $decoded->{ln};
```

or

```
my %return_result = (
    fn => $decoded->{fn},
    ln => $decoded->{ln},
);
```

or simply

```
# http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5200delta.html#New-slice-syntax
my %return_result = %$decoded{qw(fn ln)};
```

You do not get automatic references like in other languages. Use the [`\` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

```
$self->session(returnResult => \%return_result);
```

Comment: Welcome back! Haven't seen you in a while. :-)